# Unable to run gradle unit tests in parallel

Tags: gradle, junit, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am trying to run my test suite in parallel using gradle.
The test suite is a group of quite a few number of classes and the whole suite takes more than 30 minutes to run, with little over 1200 test cases.

My current gradle configuration for tests is :

```
task myTests(type: Test) {

include '**/MyTests.class'
systemProperties = ['test.group': 'myTests']
systemProperties["junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled"] = true
systemProperties["junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default"] = "concurrent"
maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
```

}

This is all I could find related to running test cases in parallel using gradle.
Below is my class definition for the tests :

```
RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
.

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


})
public class MyTests{
}
```

But still I havent seen any reduction in the execution time of tests.

Is there a way I can do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using? (You will need to be on 5.4 or later, with 5.6.2 being the latest at this time).

Comment: I am using jUnit-jupiter 5.3.1. I will try updating the version.